# What all things I can create with a cheap and a expensive 3d printer

Tags: printer-building

I am trying to getting started a 3d printer product research so I need some guidance

Comment: Welcome to SE.3DP, but I'm afraid that questions like this really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. Also, the [*3DP* question checklist](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/340) has good advice on how to write a good question. If you [edit] your question to fit our community guidelines we can reopen it for you.

Comment: Figure out your budget, and see what's available in that price range.  You might also join [chat] for a less structured conversation than the Q&A can provide.

Comment: @Criggie Unfortunately, the OP doesn't have the [privilege](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) to enter the chat.

Comment: @0scar not yet anyway :)  OP can ask some more on-topic specific questions or provide some answers, both that earn upvotes which translates to reputation.